# Access/Update a shared database

Tags: java, mysql, database, ms-access, sharing

I need to share a mysql or ms-access database between a java swing application and a mobile device. The mobile has wifi access. The java application will run on my local pc (having no access to wi-fi i.e. the pc and mobile are on different networks) and will access/update the database. The mobile device will access a webpage (that utilizes the shared database) to get/post data.

If i host the webpage using free hosting (using either asp.net or php) and access it via mobile device, it can access/update the database. How can my local java swing application access the remote database on the free hosting website?

Is there another approach that i can take to achieve a shared database?

Comment: It comes down to putting and getting data to a webserver that via a (PHP) page stores and retrieves the data from the database. Mind security.

Answer (score 0):

If your host allows direct MySQL connections (usually on port 3306), then you can access the remote database via the [Connector/J JDBC driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) provided by MySQL.

If not, then your Java application can access the database through the same PHP (or ASP.net) interface as your mobile application.